# How to read from textfield using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So here's the thing am trying to do:
I have a textfield and am writing things inside of it.

Using ajax am able to change the content of a div, by setting its content to whatever there is in the textfield.

However the problem is that am using the onChange event of the textfield! Is there a way to make the div content change automatically (in real-time) rather than using the onChange event?

Comment: Have you thought how will the `div` know when it has to get updated ?

Comment: You're not using Ajax, but javascript. Ajax is the techniques for asynchronously exchanging data with a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onkeydown` event instead.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do a lot of dependency tracking yourself if you have more than one instance of such stuff.

Have a look http://knockoutjs.com/. It will do it for you, although I would use it if i had more than one places where i could use that.

You could also look at Angularjs and Emberjs - for other features.
(HandlerbarsJS might also have some dependency tracking - but i m not sure of that)